# Inefficient execution plan on MySQL query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a performance issue with MySQL ; it seems execution plan for my request is far from optimal, but I don't know why MySQL chooses it nor how I could change it. I reproduced the issue within a minimal environment, and here is the query:

```
SELECT member.id, member_cache.id, section.id, topic.id
FROM topic
INNER JOIN (section
    INNER JOIN (member
        LEFT JOIN (member_cache) ON member_cache.id = member.id
    ) ON member.id = section.last_member
) ON section.id = topic.section
WHERE topic.last_time IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY topic.last_time DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

And here are the tables used in this query:

```
CREATE TABLE `member` (`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL)
    ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
CREATE TABLE `member_cache` (`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL)
    ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE `section` (`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, `last_member` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0')
    ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
CREATE TABLE `topic` (`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, `section` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, `last_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL)
    ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `member` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `member_cache` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `section`ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `topic` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `section__last_time` (`section`,`last_time`), ADD KEY `last_time` (`last_time`);
```

Now here is execution plan, obtained with "EXPLAIN <the query above>":

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                | key                | key_len | ref                           | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | section      | ALL    | PRIMARY                      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                          | 2188 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | member       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                      | PRIMARY            | 4       | temporary.section.last_member |    1 | Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | member_cache | eq_ref | PRIMARY                      | PRIMARY            | 4       | temporary.section.last_member |    1 | Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | topic        | ref    | section__last_time,last_time | section__last_time | 4       | temporary.section.id          |  106 | Using index condition           |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

As you can see it starts by scanning the entire "section" table, using a temporary table and causing terrible performances. I don't really understand why this happens, since an index exists on both "topic.last_time" (used in WHERE clause) and "section.id" (used in first INNER JOIN). I also did several tests and this result is pretty unstable:

- If I add an explicit "FORCE INDEX" statement on the "topic" table then obviously MySQL correctly uses indices "topic.last_time" and "section.id", ending up with a much faster result as you can see below (but I can't generate this kind of MySQL specific extension from the SQL query generation library I'm using)
- If I replace first "INNER JOIN" (against "section" table) by a "LEFT JOIN" I have the same result, probably because it prevents MySQL from reversing operands of the JOIN (but LEFT JOIN is not what I'd like to express) ;
- Weirder: if I remove index "section__last_time" from table "topic", then I also get the same result. I really don't understand why this index has an impact on execution plan? (and anyway I need it for other queries so I can't remove it)

Here is the execution plan I have after applying any of the three changes above:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref                           | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | topic        | index  | last_time     | last_time | 4       | NULL                          |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | section      | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | temporary.topic.section       |    1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | member       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | temporary.section.last_member |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | member_cache | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | temporary.section.last_member |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

I also tried to "OPTIMIZE TABLE" all tables or switch to InnoDB engine but neither of those changed anything. Issue was reproduced on MySQL versions 5.5.35 and 5.6.15 ; I also uploaded a snapshot of the test environment [here](http://www.mirari.fr/jPBs), where the queries above can be easily reproduced.

Do you know what could explain this execution plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding an index on section.last_member, section.id.

```
ALTER TABLE section ADD KEY(last_member, id);
```

If they are innodb you can omit ID since it is already a PK.

Comment: Indeed it works, thanks! Would you know why execution plan with full table scan is chosen without this extra index? I don't really understand how such an inefficient solution can be considered as the best approach by MySQL.

Comment: (and I'd like to know how to adapt your solution to my real world scenario)

Comment: Older versions of mysql have pretty simple plan optimizers. Without the secondary index the section table is joined with topic OK but members becomes an non indexed join, thus resulting in a full table scan (I think).

Comment: Hmm without any additional index it could be resolved by `topic.last_time` (index) then `section.id` (PK), `member.id` (PK) and `member_cache.id` (PK) ; that's actually what happens if I explicitely force usage of one of those indices, without having to update schema. I still don't really get it, but anyway thanks for your help :)